# JavaScript image resize results in white/black image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dropzone.js

Starting with Chrome 77 (3 dots > settings > about chrome), resizing images with JavaScript seem to be broken.

Repro steps:

1- using Chrome mobile (needs to be mobile) navigate to https://www.dropzonejs.com/

2- ensure the load photo area is almost outside the viewport (scroll down until you can barely see it)

3- select 2 photos from your phone (use real photos with normal camera settings and you will end up with 3 to 6mb/photo)

4- while photos are loading, scroll down as much as you can

5- wait until the thumbnail generation finishes (it is actually resizing the images)

6- Scroll up (BOOM)

7- some thumbnails will be white instead of displaying the real photo

This behaviour is only present in Chrome Mobile, starting from version 77. Works fine on desktop and other browsers.

Other image resizing algorithms have the same issue.

Any ideas?